# Percentages on Slices of ZingChart Pie Chart

Tags: zingchart

(I asked a similar question once before, but the issue has cropped up again.)

I have a very simple pie chart using ZingCharts, but even though all of the examples on the ZingCharts site show percentages on each slice, I can't get the percentages to show.  Note that I am using value boxes. I am using the most recent version of ZingCharts from the CDN:  https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js

Note that I am looking for the percentage to appear ON the slice, not in the value box which is text attached to each slice by a line.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="pie-chart">&nbsp;</div>

<script>
var slices = var slices = slices = [
    {"values":[59],"text":"USA"},
    {"values":[55],"text":"UK"}
];

var chartData = {
    "type":"pie",
  "plot":{
    "value-box":{
      "visible":true,
      "placement":"out",
      "text":"%t (%v)"
    }
  },
    "series": slices
};

zingchart.render({
        id:"pie-chart",
        data: chartData,
        height:400,
        width:"100%"
    });
</script>
```

I want to use a standard pie chart, not a pie chart with more effects.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle that shows it:  https://jsfiddle.net/msalamon/h0517t90/3/

Answer (score 5):

To show the percentage value on charts, you would need to use the `%npv` (node-percent-value) token instead of `%v` which displays the raw value. More information in the pie chart types page : http://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/pie/

Note that the default functionality for a value box is

```
       "value-box" : {
          "placement" : "in",
          "text" : "%npv%"
       }
```

Therefore, you can choose to omit that from your JSON. In the example below, I have shown the JSON with the options explicitly.

```js
var slices = [
  {"values":[59],"text":"USA"},
  {"values":[55],"text":"UK"}
];
var chartData = {
    "type":"pie",
    "series": slices,
    "plot" : {
       "value-box" : {
          "placement" : "in",
          "text" : "%npv%"
       }
     }
};

zingchart.render({
        id:"pie-chart",
        data: chartData,
        height:400,
        width:"100%"
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
<div id="pie-chart"></div>
```

Comment: I wasn't asking about the percentage appearing in the value box (the text separated from each slice by a line), but having the percentage appear ON the slice.  Just  using %npv will only change the value box.

Comment: The value-box in your json has the placement set to "out". Change it to "in", and the value box should appear on the slice. What version of ZingChart are you using? The percentages appear on each pie slice by default in v2.2.0+ .

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the "in" vs the "out" placement.  I am using I assume the  most recent version, as I am accessing the CDN hosted script. Just checked: 2.2.2.   That's what's weird. Every example on the ZingChart site shows the percentage appearing on the slice and in the JS that they show, there is no configuration setting for that, but I cannot recreate it.

Comment: Mike.  Thanks. Is there any way to have both in and out, so the percentage is shown inside and the text/values are shown outside with the line?

Comment: There is no way to have value-boxes displayed inside and outside. You can however, mimic this capability with using labels and the property hook to place the labels on each pie slice : http://jsfiddle.net/rprwea56/1/ . %npv is not available on text of a label so you would have to input that manually. You could also use a special token to grab a node's value from a label, but the percentages would have to be outside the pie : http://jsfiddle.net/hkrwc36k/